# Linearization of nested absolute value objective $|a-b-|c||$

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, constraints, linearization

I am trying to define an optimization problem that minimizes the distance between $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, where I need to adjust $b(x)$ downwards using the cost function $c(x)$ (hence, the cost must always be positive). Given that I require a linear problem (since IP or MIP would explode the computation time because of the scale of the problem), and given that absolute value minimization can be linearized ([see here](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Optimization_with_absolute_values)), this problem can be written as follows:

$$ \begin{align}
   \min\ &|a(x)-b(x)-|c(x)|| \\\\
   \text{such that} \quad &Ax \leq d \\\\
   \end{align}
$$

Given that the piece-wise linear objective $\min\ |X|$ can be represented using the linear objective $\min\ Z$ with the added restrictions $Z \geq X, Z \geq -X$, I can rewrite above problem as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\min z \\\\
\text{such that} \quad y &\geq +c(x) \\\\
y &\geq -c(x) \\\\
z &\geq +(a(x)-b(x)-y) \\\\
z &\geq -(a(x)-b(x)-y) \\\\
Ax &\leq d \\\\
\end{align} $$

Would such a transformation for nested absolute values work as expected? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but are the first two inequalities supposed to encode the condition "$y\geq |c|$"?

Comment: @Zim Indeed. I'm replacing the absolute value in the objective function with another variable that is constrained to be larger than the absolute value of the expression. This works because the objective is to *minimize* the absolute value. See e.g. https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Optimization_with_absolute_values

Comment: ah yeah, I've seen reformulations like this before. Looks right to me!

Comment: @Zim My question is whether it still works if done twice. Because in my case the absolute values are nested. Do you think it would still work correctly?

Comment: Ah, I see it's a bit more complicatd now since $y$ is no longer in the objective, so the replacement of $y=|c|$ with $y\geq |c|$ is not necessarily equivalent. It sortof looks like $y$ is still being minimized a bit, since it appears in the lower bound of the final 2 inequalities, but it's not super clear to me that it's actually equivalent.

Comment: In general, as far as I know the ["Active Signature Method" of Griewank and Walther](https://sci-hub.st/https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10556788.2018.1546856?needAccess=true) is the best way to handle unconstrained minimization of piecewise linear functions like this one

Comment: @Zim Thanks for the tip! This question is for an extension of a method I'm writing a paper about. Since we're already using a reinforcement learning algorithm on top of the LP problem, I don't want to add yet another algorithm simply to linearize the absolute values - which is why I'm hoping that I can get away with adding a couple of constraints instead.

Comment: Makes sense, yeah it may be possible for something this simple but I'm not so sure. good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you proposed is almost correct, but it allows $y > |c|$ at optimality when you instead want $y = |c|$.  Suppose $\underline{c} \le c \le \overline{c}$ for some constants $\underline{c}$ and $\overline{c}$. You can repair your formulation by introducing a binary variable $z$ and imposing two additional linear big-M constraints:
\begin{align}
y - c &\le (\overline{c} - \underline{c}) z \\
y + c &\le 2\overline{c}(1-z)
\end{align}
These enforce two logical implications:
\begin{align}
z = 0 &\implies y \le c \\
z = 1 &\implies y \le -c
\end{align}